Not able to generate swagger v3 for java project
I am trying to migrate our spring boot 3.x java tomcat project from swagger 2 to swagger 3 to generate API documentation.
The current setup uses swagger-core and related libs along with of a web.xml and ApplicationConfig.java to set the configuration. I made changes based on the examples provided in the swagger-core wiki with ApplicationConfig.java and web.xml setup, openapi-configuration.json and web.xml setup but none of them worked for as I believe I making some mistake while configuring.
I have changed all the annotations to match with what is specified in OAS v3. and as we are using ant to build our project and we don't use ivy. I can understand ant is really old but as of now due to time constraint we will not be able to move away from it for a while.

Also I would like to keep the setup like this if possible and not use springfox or springdoc for this.

These are the changes I tried to generate swagger.

for ApplicationConfig.java, I have removed BeanConfig and changed imports to match swagger v3
for web.xml, I have added swagger v3 resource package and removed older Jersey2Config servlet

ApplicationConfig.java
package com.org.ocsdm.ws.rest.resources.common;
import com.org.ocsdm.ws.rest.resources.common.FileResource;
import com.org.ocsdm.ws.rest.resources.internal.*;
import com.org.ocsdm.ws.rest.resources.common.SessionResource;

import io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.resources.OpenApiResource;
import io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.resources.AcceptHeaderOpenApiResource;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.integration.SwaggerConfiguration;
import io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.SwaggerSerializers;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import jakarta.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

@ApplicationPath("/ums")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public ApplicationConfig() {
        try {
            // These class files were present previously as well
            this.register(FileResource.class);
            this.register(CallBackResource.class);
            this.register(CertificateResource.class);
            this.register(DeviceTrapResource.class);
            this.register(RegistrationResource.class);
            this.register(SwaggerSerializers.class);
            this.register(OpenApiResource.class);

            SwaggerConfiguration oasConfig = new SwaggerConfiguration()
                 .openAPI(new OpenAPI()
                     .info(new Info()
                         .title("Your API Title")
                         .version("v1.1")
                         .description("Your API Description")))
                 .prettyPrint(true)
                 .resourcePackages(Stream.of("com.org.ocsdm.ws.rest").collect(Collectors.toSet()));
                 
             OpenApiResource openApiResource = new OpenApiResource();
             openApiResource.setOpenApiConfiguration(oasConfig);
             this.register(openApiResource);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("AA:: Exception " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

web.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="xwebService_ID">
  <display-name>UMS Rest Service</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j2.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>com.org.ocsdm.ws.rest.resources.common.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param> // made changes here
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>
        com.org.ocsdm.ws.rest,
        io.swagger.v3.jaxrs2.integration.resources
      </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
      <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ums/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404error.html</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/500error.html</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>

I am not able to view swagger on this link.. (I access my application on link http://100.77.43.231:8080)
http://localhost:8080/ums/openapi.json
I need to resolve the issue and generate swagger for my application. Please provide suggestions and let me know if you need more info
